# Duplicates and counting them in List

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

This is part of the code that I need to edit:

```
private static void SaveMetalToFile(List<Ring> rings)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Metalai.txt"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("|Metalai |Kiekis|");
        string message = String.Empty;

        var ringDataList = rings.GroupBy(r => r.Metalas).Select(x => new { Ring = x.FirstOrDefault(), Count = x.Count() }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in ringDataList)
        {
            message = "|" + item.Ring.Metalas + "|" + item.Count + "|";
            writer.WriteLine("{0}; {1}", ring.Metalas, message);
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to avoid putting duplicates in the Metalai.txt file but also count how many duplicates there are. I have done about 3 ways and my teacher said that its bad even though it worked. He said that I have to use 2 variables
(`writer.WriteLine("{0}; {1}", ring.Metalas, message)`)

But the problem is that I can't get it to work. He said that I cant do any maths in this list. There should be 2 methods/functions. The first one should read only metal data and distinct it and the second one should count the duplicates. No matter how I tried i couldn't get it to work.

`message = "|" + item.Ring.Metalas + "|" + item.Count + "|";` is wrong cause it uses math (addition). can you guys help me out?

Comment: That's not addition, that's string concatenation. If you're concerned about using the symbol `+`, you can use [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784338.aspx) instead. Although note that `=` is also a mathematical symbol..

Comment: `The first one should read only metal data and distinct it and the second one should count the duplicates.` If the first method makes the list distinct there are no duplicates left. Enumerable.Distinct is used to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. There are many ways to do this, but I always like using dictionaries or hashsets to perform such tasks as you're asking. As for your printing, I think your teacher was saying that you can do all the formatting within string.Format(...);

```
    private static void SaveMetalToFile(List<Ring> rings)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> finalCollection = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach(Ring item in rings)
        {
            if(finalCollection.ContainsKey(item.Metalas))
            {
                finalCollection[item.Metalas]++;//incement duplicate count
            }
            else
            {
                finalCollection.Add(item.Metalas, 1);//add if not exist with count of 1
            }
        }

        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Metalai.txt"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("|Metalai |Kiekis|");
            foreach(var item in finalCollection)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("{0};|{0}|{1}|", item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[System.String,_23LBUzduotis.Ring]' to type '_23LBUzduotis.Ring'.
   at _23LBUzduotis.Program.SaveMetalToFile(List`1 rings) in G:\New folder\23LBUzduotis\Program.cs:line 67
   at _23LBUzduotis.Program.Main(String[] args) in G:\New folder\23LBUzduotis\Program.cs:line 19

Comment: It doesnt like this line: 67:    foreach (Ring item in rings.GroupBy(r => r.Metalas).ToList())

Comment: Sorry about that. Just using rings in the foreach loop is what you need to do.

Comment: Are you sure, I just ran this code and it gives a text output below. The code in this post is up to date.

Comment: |Metalai |Kiekis|
first;|first|2|
Second;|Second|2|
third;|third|2|
fourth;|fourth|1|

Comment: Well I did replase item with ring not rings cause that gives me even more errors

Comment: Have You tried just copy and pasting the code to run it? I'm not sure what's causing you problems without seeing your code if it's different from what's above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that you edited the code. Now it works perfectly. Thank you so much! I just hope that it will be okay for my teacher cause it's the 4th different combination lol.

Comment: Best of luck! Just remember, there was a time where your very teacher was struggling to learn all these concepts. It does get easier!